# unable to save the tensorflow hub model of universal lite with tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm unable to save the model, after trained my data by using a hub model of universal lite 2(https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2).

```
tensorflow== 1.15  tensorflow_hub=0.7.0  python =3.7.6  OS = Window 10 64 bit
```

**I saved model local**

```
path =&quot;C:/Users/771556/Downloads/ModelLiteUSE&quot;  #url =&quot;https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2&quot;  liteModule = hub.Module(path)

input_placeholder = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, None])  encodings = liteModule(  inputs=dict(  values=input_placeholder.values,  indices=input_placeholder.indices,  dense_shape=input_placeholder.dense_shape))

with tf.Session() as sess:  spm_path = sess.run(liteModule(signature=&quot;spm_path&quot;))

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()  sp.Load(spm_path)  print(&quot;SentencePiece model loaded at {}.&quot;.format(spm_path))

def process_to_IDs_in_sparse_format(sp, sentences):    ids = [sp.EncodeAsIds(x) for x in sentences]  max_len = max(len(x) for x in ids)  dense_shape=(len(ids), max_len)  values=[item for sublist in ids for item in sublist]  indices=[[row,col] for row in range(len(ids)) for col in range(len(ids[row]))]  return (values, indices, dense_shape)

def embed(input):  values, indices, dense_shape = process_to_IDs_in_sparse_format(sp, input)  # Reduce logging output.  logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)  with tf.Session() as session:  session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])  message_embeddings = session.run(  encodings,  feed_dict={input_placeholder.values: values,  input_placeholder.indices: indices,  input_placeholder.dense_shape: dense_shape})  return message_embeddings
```

**Training the data**

```
TrainModel= embed(file_data.text)
```

**Saving model**

```
tf.saved_model.save(TrainModel,'D:/liteTrainmodel')
```

**Error**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please format you properly.

Comment: how to do it, if you know, pls share code.

Comment: Kindly find the Colab url:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r7nPKTL4SWhkBvXQ3mr42iXm8cA17xJ0

Comment: @ZayedRais, I have gone through your colab and have observed that there is no Model as such. You can define a Model and then you can try Saving it. If you don't want to define a Model. Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve, so that we can try to help you? Thanks!